# error when trying to open solution with Ribbon workbench

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I'm working with CRM 2016, I downloaded Ribbon workbench 2016, its installed successfully.

I tried to open a solution and I got this error message.
system.servicemodel.security.securitynegotiationexception: microsoft dynamic crm has experience an error

I searched for that and I found that maybe this error come when there is different version between CRM and Ribbon but in my case all of them is 2016.[image]

can anyone help me in this.
attached the error that I got.
thanks,

Comment: This should not happen Online (looks like a SPN issue), I suggest opening a Support Ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening Ribbon workbench from xrmtoolbox solve my problem.

Comment: Your solution is the one I would have advised. From experience depending on the Solution i'm working on, I sometimes will have to open it from XRMToolbox or from the Ribbon Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue try the below 2 solutions,

1. First do publish All Customization
2. 2nd Switch between Ribbonworkbench tool one from XRMToolBox or Ribbonworkbench Managed solution.